# naming of JSF components in PrimeFaces

Tags: jquery, primefaces

I have this code that works although I would expect it to fail. The component to receive focus is the `<p:inputText>` so I would expect its name to be `custForm:panelGrid:name-id` (to reflect the embedding of the `<p:inputText>` component within the `<p:panelGrid>` component). Yet the only naming that works is `custForm:name-id`. It appears that there are some PrimeFaces components which do not "insert" their **id** in the qualified name. If so, where is that documented?

```
<h:form id="custForm" styleClass="jsfcrud_list_form">
<script type="text/javascript">
  function primeFacesId()
  {
        var original = 'custForm:name-id';
        var idToSetFocus = PrimeFaces.escapeClientId(original);
        $(idToSetFocus).focus();
  }
</script>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        primeFacesId();
    });
</script>
<p:panelGrid columns="10" style="width: 98%;margin-left: 1%;margin-right: 1%;" id="panelGrid">
    <h:outputLabel for="name" value="Name:" />
    <p:inputText   id="name-id" value="#{customerLController.nameDBConstraint}" label="name" />
        (...)
```

*[I am behind corporate firewall and due to the "SO requires external JavaScript from another domain" I won't be able to accept any answers for a couple of days]*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For plain JSF all components that implement the [NamingContainer](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.1/javadocs/javax/faces/component/NamingContainer.html) interface add their id as prefix to all components inside the container. This is for instance `h:form` or `h:dataTable` but not `h:panelGrid`. You can browse the [API documentation for Mojarra](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.1/javadocs/index.html) to get detailed information on that.

Since many Primefaces components are derived from standard JSF components, I think their behavior is similar.

UPDATE:
I found this in the Primefaces documentation for version 3.2:

> JSF h:form, datatable, composite components are naming containers, in
>   addition tabView, accordionPanel, dataTable, dataGrid, dataList,
>   carousel, galleria, ring, sheet and subTable are PrimeFaces component
>   that implement NamingContainer.

At least for `p:panelGrid` this is not true (and can be verified in the html source of the [PF showcase for the panelgrid](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panelGrid.jsf)).